# Too small sample size for Wilcoxon signed rank test, alternatives?

Tags: normality-assumption, small-sample, paired-data, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I have a statistical question about my research.

I performed photosynthesis measurements on leaves. I have 6 increasing light intensities, and for every light intensity, I measured the photosynthetic efficiency when I applied far red light and when far red light was switched off on the same leaf (paired data). Now I want to compare the value of photosynthesis when the far red light was on and when it was off for every light intensity ( but not between light intensities). I wanted to run a paired t-test, which was fine for some light intensity levels. However I also have a light intensity level where the Normality assumption is violated, which would bring me to Wilcoxon signed rank test. But since my n=4, the P-value can never be lower than 0,0625 (and not below a=0.05). I thought about post hoc LSD/Tukey, but it is not meaningful to compare the increasing light intensities with each other (only the far red and no far red value). Does anyone know a solution to this problem?

[image: So for example the first leaf, I switch on 50umol of light and measure photosynthesis, then I keep 50umol on and add far red light and measure it again. Then I switch to the next intensity (150umol) and do exactly the same on the same leaf, and so on for the remaining four intensities. In total, I repeated this procedure for four leaves. I want to know whether "50umol no far red " significantly differs from "50umol with far red", and again the same for the other light intensities.]

So for example the first leaf, I switch on 50umol of light and measure photosynthesis, then I keep 50umol on and add far red light and measure it again. Then I switch to the next intensity (150umol) and do exactly the same on the same leaf, and so on for the remaining four intensities. In total, I repeated this procedure for four leaves. I want to know whether "50umol no far red " significantly differs from "50umol with far red", and again the same for the other light intensities.
[image: This is how it looks like, only measured at other intensities then I mentioned (FR means far red, minus sign means without, plus sign means with)]

This is how it looks like, only measured at other intensities then I mentioned (FR means far red, minus sign means without, plus sign means with

Comment: I am not sure to well understand the experiment. Do you only have 4 pairs of data points in total, or is it for each light intensity ? Do you perform a test for each light intensity or just a global one ?

Comment: For each light intensity I have 4 pairs, and I perform a test for each light intensity.

Comment: I agree w/ @Pohoua that the study is a little hard to follow. Can you post a small example dataset? They can be similar, fake data, if there's some confidentiality issue.

Comment: Yes, I agree with gung. A bit of data would be nice.
How did you tell that normality assumption does not hold if you only have 4 data points (it seems to me like it's too little to either accept or reject normality) ?

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I edited the post above. Hope it is clear now.

Comment: You seem to have a more complicated design than is suitable for either Student's t or the Wilcoxon signed rank test. Have you thought of repeated measures ANOVA? A few more leaves might help too but I assume they are too expensive or rare.